# Share pane between tmux sessions

Tags: tmux

Is there any way to share a single pane between two different sessions?

In the picture below there are two windows each with their own single-window session with a 3 panes. The pink square is a single pane that is plugged into both sessions.

This would be useful for always showing test output on a monitor while also having it available to type into sometimes on a larger desktop session.

[image: tmux shared pane]

Comment: it seems that you cannot do it with current tmux. however, you can share window between sessions. and, you can pipe-pane for your log output, join-pane to move pane between different windows/sessions

Comment: To share a window between two sessions: `tmux link-window -s <src-window> -t <dst-window>` (mainly a reminder to my self (-: )

Comment: You _could_ use the same nested tmux session in both panes, with a separate configuration hiding any indication thereof...